# Sort columns in a stacked chart by value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to sort individual columns in a stacked chart by size (ascending order). The chart has been created using a Pivot Table. I have ranked the values across all the columns (by value size) but still having trouble sorting columns individually by value. Please see image below. How do I get the order of the first column to sorted by size?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Series are always plotted in the same order across all data points so you can't sort one column differently to another if the same series are involved.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this? Please see above for more details

Comment: For that example, since there is no overlap, you can simply sort the columns by the values, then the chart will be in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - sorting the values in the pivot order the graph.

[image]